# How to install vimtex.txt helpfile properly?

Tags: help-system, plugin-vimtex, plugin-pathogen

I'm using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) (from the Ubuntu 16.04 `vim-pathogen` package) and a git clone of [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/) in `~/.vim/bundle/vimtex/`. Now `:help vimtex` does not work. I can read `~/.vim/bundle/vimtex/doc/vimtex.txt`, but vim displays it as plain text and thus the tags do not work for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Run `:Helptags` after installing a new package. Then `:help vimtex` works.